# Python requests remove the Content-Length header from POST

Tags: python, http, python-requests, http-content-length

I'm using the python requests module to do some testing against a site.

The requests module allows you to remove certain headers by passing in a dictionary with the keys set to None. For example

```
headers = {u'User-Agent': None}
```

will ensure that no user agent is sent with the request.

However, it seems that when I post data, requests will calculate the correct Content-Length for me even if I specify None, or an incorrect value. Eg.

```
headers = {u'Content-Length': u'999'}
headers = {u'Content-Length': None}
```

I check the response for the headers used in the request (response.request.headers) and I can see the Content-Length has been re-added with the correct value. So Far I cannot see any way to disable this behaviour

```
CaseInsensitiveDict({'Content-Length': '39', 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, compress', 'Accept': '*/*', 'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.2.1 CPython/2.7.6 Linux/3.13.0-36-generic'})
```

I'd REALLY like to remain with the requests module to do this. Is this possible?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You'll have to [prepare the request manually](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/advanced/#prepared-requests), then remove the generated content-length header:

```
from requests import Request, Session

s = Session()
req = Request('POST', url, data=data)
prepped = req.prepare()
del prepped.headers['content-length']
response = s.send(prepped)
```

Do note that most compliant HTTP servers may then *ignore* your post body!

If you meant to use [chunked transfer encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding) (where you don't have to send a content length), then use a iterator for the `data` parameter. See [*Chunked-Encoded Requests*](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/advanced/#chunk-encoded-requests) in the documentation. No `Content-Length` header will be set in that case.

Comment: FYI, Requests >= 2.0, as well as built-in `urllib.request` and `http.client` in Python >= 3.6, swtich to `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` automatically when `Content-Length` is not present. See https://github.com/psf/requests/commit/ef8563ab36c6b52834ee9c35f6f75a424cd9ceef and https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/3c0d0baf2badfad7deb346d1043f7d83bb92691f .

I wasted quite a lot of time trying to submit a request without `Content-Length` before finding this out.

Comment: @selurvedu: the content header is not added when using an iterator for the data parameter, or if the body otherwise doesn't have a length. At that point `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` is used, which is what I refer to with my last paragraph.

Comment: @ Martijn, sure, that's what I was saying. I missed the iterator part, but using an iterator implies that content length cannot be easily determined.

Comment: @selurvedu: yes, which is the point. If content length can easily be determined, you definitely should use a content length in your request.