# Python Requests adds additional headers to any GET or POST request

Tags: python, python-requests

For the simple request like following with python requests

```
r = requests.get("http://google.com", headers={'Connection': 'close'})
```

There are additional request headers sent with request like following

```
>>> r.request.headers
{'Connection': 'close', 'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.9.1', 'Accept': '*/*', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate'}
```

Is there any way to force python requests to just send the supplied headers and nothing more?

Thank you,
Sudu

Comment: Have you tried providing empty values for those headers in your `headers={...}` value?

Comment: And in fact, what have you tried?

Comment: Thank you for quick response. Yeah I added `Connection` header in the request and along with it there are more headers like `Accept: */*` which I don't want to be seen

Comment: Have you tried looking at the source code for `requests`?

Comment: Yep. I'll check it out. Thank you Barny! :)

Comment: Have you even bothered to try searching? I very easily found this by using a popular search engine https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27043402/python-requests-remove-the-content-length-header-from-post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to send all other headers as `None`.
For example:-

```
headers = {'Connection': 'close', 'Accept-Encoding': None, 'User-Agent': None}
r = requests.get("http://google.com", headers=headers)
```

P.S - But some websites may fail to respond if you send them as `None`

Comment: Thank you! :)
setting `None` value to default headers ['Connection','User-Agent','Accept','Accept-Encoding'] sent by requests worked for my application. :)

Answer (score 0):

Please try 'head':

```
>>> r = requests.head('http://google.com',headers={'Connection':'close'})                                                               
>>> r.request.headers
{'Connection': 'close', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Accept': '*/*', 'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.19.1'}                    
>>> r.text                                                                                                                              
u''
```

Answer (score 0):

**There are additional request headers sent with request like following**

```
headers = {'Connection': 'close',  'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Accept': '*/*', 'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.19.1'}
r = requests.get("http://google.com", headers=headers)
```

Comment: OP already knows this. The question is not _whether_ they are sent, but rather how to _prevent_ those additional headers.